# Set Navigation on-hover with a set time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have navigation menu with div wrap around a ul and li

```
<div>
    <li><a>Menu item One</a><div id=flyMenuOne></div></li>
    <li><a>Menu item Two</a><div id=flyMenuOne></div></li>
    <li><a>Menu item Three</a><div id=flyMenuOne></div></li>
    <li><a>Menu item Four</a><div id=flyMenuOne></div></li>
    <li><a>Menu item Five</a><div id=flyMenuOne></div></li>
</div>
```

the div is set to display:none; however the css onhover is to effective any way to make a jquery that will only fire a function if a user hovers over for more then 2 seconds?

any help would be great thank you.

Comment: what you are looking for is probably this: http://api.jquery.com/delay/ and by the way there are a lot of questions like yours in SO so search before ask.

Comment: I don't think `delay()` is appropriate in this case. I would use `setTimeout` and `cancelTimeout` in conjunction with `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

Comment: tried delay however the function will fire just in a delay i'm trying to avoid firing a function if the user intent was to navigate somewhere else.